Alternative aside from using rotary evaporator and shaking incubator
I am a high school student and our research study is about exploring the antimicrobial activity of plant stem extract against e. coli. Now for extraction method we need shaking incubator ang rotary evaporator for maceration method for extraction but my school doesn't have complete materials, what is the alternative way for extraction aside from using shaking incubator and rotary evaporator for concentration of the solution?

I don't really understand what you are trying to accomplish. Are you just trying to stir some stuff at a relatively constant temperature, or are you trying to reduce volume? If you include what the actual task will be, it is easier to suggest replacements (if there are any good ones).

Maceration is mashing. What does that have to do with incubator and evaporator?

What solvent are you using for the extraction? Could you use a more volatile solvent (diethyl ether?) that will readily evaporate?
